# Error with autocomplete in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I load new form in colorbox pop-up window. In my form I use `ui-autocomplete` for two fields, but it does not work properly. When you type in the drop-down list appears under the colorbox, but it is decided by a simple css z-index. The problem is that I can `t choose any item from this list, in any event, the list disappears. Autocomplete version is 1.10.3, colorbox - 1.3.23.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You can override `jquery-ui css` or `colorbox css`.

The `z-index` for `colorbox` is 9999, so put 10000 in `.ui-front` in your own css for example :

```
.ui-front {
    z-index:10000;
}
```

(Remember that your css have to be placed after the jquery one)

Comment: I`m set z-index for ui-front class, but thet not problem, problem is i can`t choice any item from drop-down list, he simple hide if I press any key or hover mouse on list...